# cdonts and relay server?

Tags: asp-classic

I use CDONTS when I need to send up send email form on websites. Recently changed my hosting company to godaddy. I realized my send email form gives "permission denied" error. I called GoDaddy support. They told me I should use relay server "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" in my codes. I thought relay server used only with CDO.

How can I include it to my codes?
My codes

```
Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
objEmail.To         = MailTo
objEmail.Cc         = MailCc
objEmail.From       = MailFrom
objEmail.Subject    = MailSubject
objEmail.Body       = MailBody
objEmail.Send
Set objEmail = nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

A web search for "cdonts relay" yielded [this example](http://nicole.cfwebtools.com/index.cfm/2007/12/6/ASP%20form%20mail) which relates directly to your issue with GoDaddy.com - Based on everything I've read, this only works with `CDO.Message` instead of `CDONTS.NewMail`.

---

**UPDATE:** Here's the modified code

```
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMail.From = MailFrom
objMail.To= MailTo
objMail.Subject = MailSubject
objMail.TextBody = MailBody
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMail.Send
set ojbMail = nothing
```

Comment: I dont have an email account but I dont think I need to provide user name and password. At least that's what they told me over the phone.

Comment: According to GoDaddy, you don't need the username/password. Please see the updated code removing the authentication related lines.

Comment: I searched far and wide for this resolution. Thank you Jose. Shame GoDaddy can't update their forums.